# npm run dev not working, after installing everything that was supposedly needed

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

[The Contents of my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAi5h.png) It's throwing up that error, I have nodejs running. The system is `Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS`, hardware is Lenovo Ideapad 520-15IKB.

```bash
khonjed@pop-os:~$ npm -v
8.5.1
khonjed@pop-os:~$ npm run dev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/khonjed/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/khonjed/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/khonjed/.npm/_logs/2023-12-03T17_29_06_174Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried updating everything, but still nothing works... Attached also is a picture of my logs found at `/home/khonjed/.npm/_logs/2023-12-03T17_29_06_174Z-debug-0.log`:

[image: terminal output]

Comment: What does your `package.json` file look like (update your question with its contents) and where is it located relative to where you are running `npm run dev npm` from in the terminal?

Comment: You seem to be running it in the wrong directory

Comment: And this is the error i get when in run it in the directory which I suppose you are saying I should have run from.

khonjed@pop-os:~/test_project_laravel$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

file:///home/khonjed/test_project_laravel/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
    await import('source-map-support').then((r) => r.default.install())
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)